# How to use Featuretools to create features from multiple columns in single dataframe by column values?

Tags: python, featuretools

I'm trying to predict results of football matches based on earlier results. I'm running Python 3.6 on Windows and using Featuretools 0.4.1.

Let's say I have the following dataframe representing history of results.

[Original DataFame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w87y4.png)

Using the dataframe above I want to create the following dataframe which will be fed to machine learning algorithm as *X*. Note that goal averages for home and away teams need to be calculated by team despite their past match venues. Is there a way to create such a dataframe using [Featuretools](https://www.featuretools.com/)?

[Resulting Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ8bh.png)

Excel file used to simulate the transformation can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0AGyJsBjwP_2gDeaD7kkegiyxtSeNgk/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a tricky feature, but a great usage of a custom primitive in Featuretools.

The first step is load the CSV of matches into a Featuretools entityset

```
es = ft.EntitySet()
matches_df = pd.read_csv("./matches.csv")
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="matches",
                         index="match_id",
                         time_index="match_date",
                         dataframe=matches_df)
```

Then we define a custom transform primitive that calculates average goals scored in last n games. it has a parameter that controls the number of past games and whether or not to calculate for the home or away team. Information on defining custom primitives is in our documentation [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/primitives.html#defining-custom-primitives) and [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/guides/advanced_custom_primitives.html).

```
from featuretools.variable_types import Numeric, Categorical
from featuretools.primitives import make_trans_primitive

def avg_goals_previous_n_games(home_team, away_team, home_goals, away_goals, which_team=None, n=1):
    # make dataframe so it's easier to work with
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "home_team": home_team,
        "away_team": away_team,
        "home_goals": home_goals,
        "away_goals": away_goals
        })

    result = []
    for i, current_game in df.iterrows():
        # get the right team for this game
        team = current_game[which_team]

        # find all previous games that have been played
        prev_games =  df.iloc[:i]

        # only get games the team participated in
        participated = prev_games[(prev_games["home_team"] == team) | (prev_games["away_team"] == team)]
        if participated.shape[0] < n:
            result.append(None)
            continue

        # get last n games
        last_n = participated.tail(n)

        # calculate games per game
        goal_as_home = (last_n["home_team"] == team) * last_n["home_goals"]
        goal_as_away = (last_n["away_team"] == team) * last_n["away_goals"]

        # calculate mean across all home and away games
        mean = (goal_as_home + goal_as_away).mean()

        result.append(mean)

    return result

# custom function so the name of the feature prints out correctly
def make_name(self):
    return "%s_goal_last_%d" % (self.kwargs['which_team'], self.kwargs['n'])


AvgGoalPreviousNGames = make_trans_primitive(function=avg_goals_previous_n_games,
                                          input_types=[Categorical, Categorical, Numeric, Numeric],
                                          return_type=Numeric,
                                          cls_attributes={"generate_name": make_name, "uses_full_entity":True})
```

Now we can define features using this primitive. In this case, we will have to do it manually.

```
input_vars = [es["matches"]["home_team"], es["matches"]["away_team"], es["matches"]["home_goals"], es["matches"]["away_goals"]]
home_team_last1 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="home_team", n=1)
home_team_last3 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="home_team", n=3)
home_team_last5 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="home_team", n=5)
away_team_last1 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="away_team", n=1)
away_team_last3 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="away_team", n=3)
away_team_last5 = AvgGoalPreviousNGames(*input_vars, which_team="away_team", n=5)

features = [home_team_last1, home_team_last3, home_team_last5,
            away_team_last1, away_team_last3, away_team_last5]
```

Finally, we can calculate the feature matrix

```
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(entityset=es, features=features)
```

this returns

```
          home_team_goal_last_1  home_team_goal_last_3  home_team_goal_last_5  away_team_goal_last_1  away_team_goal_last_3  away_team_goal_last_5
match_id                                                                                                                                          
1                           NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN
2                           2.0                    NaN                    NaN                    0.0                    NaN                    NaN
3                           1.0                    NaN                    NaN                    0.0                    NaN                    NaN
4                           3.0               1.000000                    NaN                    0.0               1.000000                    NaN
5                           1.0               1.333333                    NaN                    1.0               0.666667                    NaN
6                           2.0               2.000000                    1.2                    0.0               0.333333                    0.8
7                           1.0               0.666667                    0.6                    2.0               1.666667                    1.6
8                           2.0               1.000000                    0.8                    2.0               2.000000                    2.0
9                           0.0               1.000000                    0.8                    1.0               1.666667                    1.6
10                          3.0               2.000000                    2.0                    1.0               1.000000                    0.8
11                          3.0               2.333333                    2.2                    1.0               0.666667                    1.0
12                          2.0               2.666667                    2.2                    2.0               1.333333                    1.2
```

Finally, we can also use these manually defined features as an input to the automated feature engineering using Deep Feature Synthesis, which is explained [here](https://blog.featurelabs.com/deep-feature-synthesis/). By passing the manually defined features in as `seed_features`, `ft.dfs` will automatically stack on top of them.

```
fm, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es, 
                          target_entity="matches",
                          seed_features=features, 
                          agg_primitives=[], 
                          trans_primitives=["day", "month", "year", "weekday", "percentile"])
```

`feature_defs` is

```
[<Feature: home_team>,
 <Feature: away_team>,
 <Feature: home_goals>,
 <Feature: away_goals>,
 <Feature: label>,
 <Feature: home_team_goal_last_1>,
 <Feature: home_team_goal_last_3>,
 <Feature: home_team_goal_last_5>,
 <Feature: away_team_goal_last_1>,
 <Feature: away_team_goal_last_3>,
 <Feature: away_team_goal_last_5>,
 <Feature: DAY(match_date)>,
 <Feature: MONTH(match_date)>,
 <Feature: YEAR(match_date)>,
 <Feature: WEEKDAY(match_date)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(home_goals)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(away_goals)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_1)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_3)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_5)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_1)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_3)>,
 <Feature: PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_5)>]
```

The feature matrix is

```
         home_team away_team  home_goals  away_goals label  home_team_goal_last_1  home_team_goal_last_3  home_team_goal_last_5  away_team_goal_last_1  away_team_goal_last_3  away_team_goal_last_5  DAY(match_date)  MONTH(match_date)  YEAR(match_date)  WEEKDAY(match_date)  PERCENTILE(home_goals)  PERCENTILE(away_goals)  PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_1)  PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_3)  PERCENTILE(home_team_goal_last_5)  PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_1)  PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_3)  PERCENTILE(away_team_goal_last_5)
match_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1          Arsenal   Chelsea           2           0     1                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                    NaN                1                  1              2014                    2                0.666667                0.166667                                NaN                                NaN                                NaN                                NaN                                NaN                                NaN
2          Arsenal   Chelsea           1           0     1                    2.0                    NaN                    NaN                    0.0                    NaN                    NaN                2                  1              2014                    3                0.333333                0.166667                           0.590909                                NaN                                NaN                           0.227273                                NaN                                NaN
3          Arsenal   Chelsea           0           3     2                    1.0                    NaN                    NaN                    0.0                    NaN                    NaN                3                  1              2014                    4                0.125000                0.958333                           0.272727                                NaN                                NaN                           0.227273                                NaN                                NaN
4          Chelsea   Arsenal           1           1     X                    3.0               1.000000                    NaN                    0.0               1.000000                    NaN                4                  1              2014                    5                0.333333                0.500000                           0.909091                           0.333333                                NaN                           0.227273                           0.500000                                NaN
5          Chelsea   Arsenal           2           0     1                    1.0               1.333333                    NaN                    1.0               0.666667                    NaN                5                  1              2014                    6                0.666667                0.166667                           0.272727                           0.555556                                NaN                           0.590909                           0.277778                                NaN
6          Chelsea   Arsenal           2           1     1                    2.0               2.000000                    1.2                    0.0               0.333333                    0.8                6                  1              2014                    0                0.666667                0.500000                           0.590909                           0.722222                           0.571429                           0.227273                           0.111111                           0.214286
7          Arsenal   Chelsea           2           2     X                    1.0               0.666667                    0.6                    2.0               1.666667                    1.6                7                  1              2014                    1                0.666667                0.791667                           0.272727                           0.111111                           0.142857                           0.909091                           0.833333                           0.785714
8          Arsenal   Chelsea           0           1     2                    2.0               1.000000                    0.8                    2.0               2.000000                    2.0                8                  1              2014                    2                0.125000                0.500000                           0.590909                           0.333333                           0.357143                           0.909091                           1.000000                           1.000000
9          Arsenal   Chelsea           1           3     2                    0.0               1.000000                    0.8                    1.0               1.666667                    1.6                9                  1              2014                    3                0.333333                0.958333                           0.090909                           0.333333                           0.357143                           0.590909                           0.833333                           0.785714
10         Chelsea   Arsenal           3           1     1                    3.0               2.000000                    2.0                    1.0               1.000000                    0.8               10                  1              2014                    4                0.916667                0.500000                           0.909091                           0.722222                           0.714286                           0.590909                           0.500000                           0.214286
11         Chelsea   Arsenal           2           2     X                    3.0               2.333333                    2.2                    1.0               0.666667                    1.0               11                  1              2014                    5                0.666667                0.791667                           0.909091                           0.888889                           0.928571                           0.590909                           0.277778                           0.428571
12         Chelsea   Arsenal           4           1     1                    2.0               2.666667                    2.2                    2.0               1.333333                    1.2               12                  1              2014                    6                1.000000                0.500000                           0.590909                           1.000000                           0.928571                           0.909091                           0.666667                           0.571429
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for thorough answer! I'll be able to take on from here. Cheers!

Comment: defining custom primitives  : 
Links mentioned in the answer has expired, adding the same. 
Link1 : https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/getting_started/primitives.html#Simple-Custom-Primitives  
Link 2: https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/advanced_custom_primitives.html